# JsonSchema - Defining a white-listed set of values

Tags: jsonschema, whitelist

I feel like there's no chance my question was not asked before, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

As the title suggests, I'm trying to create a JSON schema that will validate an array if, and only if, **All** of the values in it are defined in a pre-defined set.

For example:
If the predefined set contains `{"One", "Two", "Three"}`, and the array I'm trying to validate is `["One", "Two"]`, then the array should be **valid**.
But if the array is `["One", "Two", "Four"]`, then the array would be **invalid**.

So I know of `enum` but it doesn't accomplish my goal since it validates as long as **ONE** of the values is defined in the predefined set.

I also know of `min/max-contain` combinations, tho they may interfere with the requirement that none of the values in the predefined set **MUST** appear. They all may, or may not appear.

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish such requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's break that down:

- You want to validate each item of an array against a schema. That's the `items` keyword: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#items
- each item of the array should have a value that exists in a predefined set. That's the `enum` keyword: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#id4

Putting it together:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "enum": [ "one", "two", "three" ]
  }
}
```